# Is there a way to get access to parent scope from an Angular UI nested named view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have several screens in my application that contain nested views. I have found it easier to make modal dialog boxes and panels that slide in and out to be actual nested states with actual urls rather than be some arbitrary javascript magic embedded within the html. I found this approach to be good for reuse and making new pages that require dialogs and panels. It simplifies everything a great deal.

For example, here is what modal and right panel child states might look like when defined as Angular UI states:

```
    .state('courses.detail.courseVersion.page', {
        url: '/sections/:sectionId/pages/:pageId',
        templateUrl: 'app/courses/courses.detail.courseVersion.page.html',
        resolve: {
            page: function(Model, $stateParams) {
                {not relevant}
            }
        },
        controller: 'PageDetailController'
    })
    .state('courses.detail.courseVersion.page.edit', {
        url: '/edit',
        views: {
            'rightPanel@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/courses/courses.detail.courseVersion.page.edit.html',
                resolve: {
                    {not relevant}
                },
                controller: 'PageFormController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('courses.detail.courseVersion.page.delete', {
        url: '/delete',
        views: {
            'modal@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/courses/courses.detail.courseVersion.deletePage.html',
                resolve: {
                    {not relevant}
                },
                controller: 'DeletePageController'
            }
        }
    })
```

In `DeletePageController` or `PageFormController`, what I'd like to do is access the scope in `PageDetailController`. For example, if the Page's title was edited, I'd like to update the parent scope with that information rather than reload the page entirely (which is what I'm currently doing, however this defeats the entire point of using ajax).

My first instinct was to look at the value for `$scope.$parent`, however, it is actually null. This is different than when using regular nested states that don't have named views.

How can I reliably access the parent scope without using the root scope or a custom service to solve this problem? I simply want to call a function on the parent scope to update the values - this will solve my problem nicely, but it doesn't look possible without using the root scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a service that all of them share that can be accessed.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the answer, because it's a lot more structural effort for the application. I guess there's no choice. I was hoping for a way for child states to talk to their containing parent a bit more directly, since there is no reuse potential for these services at all. It is direct 1-to-1 communication between specific views.

Comment: Why are you so much against the idea of a service? It really does make sense - think of it as a backend/db or a storage or whatever - it's just a common interface to read/write data...

Answer (score 1):

Although already answered by Mathew Berg that you should use a Service to share data between controllers you CAN share/inherit scope variables (though probably not encouraged).

```
<div ng-controller="BaseCtrl">
<div ng-controller="InnerCtrl">
...
</div>
</div>

function BaseCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.shared = {
    fun : true
  };
}

function InnerCtrl($scope) {
  console.log('fun', $scope.shared.fun);
  $scope.shared.lol = 'always';
}
```

I was using a simple (working) syntax for the example. Just remember to place properties ON the shared object - do NOT overwrite it like this:

```
function InnerCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.shared = {
    lol: 'always'
  };
}
```

That will break the link to the object the BaseCtrl is holding. Sometimes you need to apply several properties and typing/copying them manually can be hard. You can do this instead:

```
function InnerCtrl($scope) {
  var model = {
    lol : 'always',
    shout: function () { console.log('yay!'); }
  };

  angular.copy($scope.shared, model); // shared now also holds lol and shout.
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of this method. It's not very "angular ui router", and I guess I was hoping for a more structured way for child views to talk to the controller that they are contained. It seemed like a use-case that makes sense is practical. I guess services will have to do. It just seems like more structural effort than what should be required.